# Edittext remove focus and don't transfer focus on the other edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I have 2 `EditText` in my view,

When I'm on my last `EditText` and pressed done on the soft keyboard.
The focus transfer back to my first `EditText` which I find annoying/wrong. It should just clear the focus and hide the keyboard

Here is my xml:

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    app:counterTextAppearance="@style/counterText"
                    app:counterOverflowTextAppearance="@style/counterOverride"
                    app:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutGold">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/mMerchantName"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
                        android:inputType ="numberDecimal"
                        app:theme="@style/EditTextGold"
                        android:hint="@string/label_merchant_name"
                        />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    app:counterTextAppearance="@style/counterText"
                    app:counterOverflowTextAppearance="@style/counterOverride"
                    app:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutGold">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
                        android:id="@+id/Transaction_amount"
                        android:inputType ="numberDecimal"
                        app:theme="@style/EditTextGold"
                        android:hint="@string/hint_transaction_amount"
                        />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: try adding `android:nextFocusDown=""  ` with next view id

Answer (score 1):

add this code for the edit text you want to focus on

```
edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
             final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        editText.requestFocus();
                    }
                }, 100);
        }    
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: i have read it already, the edittext on which you want to focus  , after typing text in that edittext when you click done softkeyboard in that methd add this method this way focus will not shift

Answer (score 0):

`editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(EditText v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
       InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
      if (view == null) {
        view = new View(activity);
    }
       imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
       return true;
    }
    return false;
    }
});`

Comment: the focus remains. nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

You can use **clearFocus()** to clear focus of edittext on your **IME_ACTION_DONE** event.

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(EditText v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
                {
                    previous_editText.clearFocus();
                    editText.clearFocus();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Updated code:

Please also add **setOnFocusChangeListener** on your editText

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
            {
                if(!hasFocus) 
                {
                    // Also check your condition becasue it will always called onfoucs change
                    // check your edit text has some entry or not 
                    previous_editText.clearFocus();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: That will just transfer the focus to the previous edittext that i have.

Comment: Please also add setOnFocusChangeListener on your editText and be aware about this it will call every time when you loose or gain focus on your editText